# Can I multiple run npm installs simultaneously

Tags: unix, terminal, npm

If I'm setting up a project and running npm install -abc xyz, can I run another npm install in another terminal instance, for the same project, whilst this is still running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install multiple packages with a single command like this:

```
npm install --save package1 package2 package3 ...
```

**EDIT:**
Installing packages separately, while theoretically possible, could create problems. When an install command is issued, npm looks up existing modules and downloads missing packages into a staging folder `.staging` inside `node_modules`. Once downloaded it copies the packages into the `node_modules` sub-folder (and removes .staging).

In npm2, modules had their own dependencies stored underneath themselves like this:

```
node_modules
  - dependencyA
    - node_modules
      - dependencyC
  - dependencyB
    - node_modules
      - dependencyC
```

Notice how dependency A and B both rely on C. If C is the same version in both cases, it would use twice the space.

In npm3, dependencies are flattened like this:

```
node_modules
  - dependencyA
  - dependencyB
  - dependencyC
```

If for some reason an older version is used in a dependency, it follows the npm2 convention for that module.

I'd stick with the intended use of npm and use the multiple install functionality.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. That will install the packages one by one but what about simultaneously? Will there be conflicts etc?

Comment: There may be a (unlikely) race condition in some cases, but nothing prevents you from doing a separate install in another terminal. What is your use case for this?

Comment: I just thought it would be faster for me to get things installed. I would start installing one package, then immediately realise it might take a bit of time, then start spinning up the next one whilst I'm waiting.

Comment: That really is not necessary and might actually complicate things. Npm checks your installed packages and their dependencies before it installs new ones. Your approach becomes especially problematic in npm3 where the modules folder is flattened. Its best and safest to let npm do its job. It does it well ;)

Comment: Yes that's more like the answer I'm looking for. What does flattening the modules folder do that makes it more complicated? If you copy your responses across I can set as answer :)

Comment: If this answers your question, please feel free to mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use the following

example

```
npm i daterangepicker select2
```

[image]